# Using two or more Arrows in a Javascript function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to fully understand the use of two or more arrows in a function. How would I re-write the below using 'function' instead and not the '=>' . This might help me to grasp it

```
 export const fetchPosts = () => async dispatch => {
  const response = await jsonPlaceholder.get('/posts')
  dispatch ({type: 'FETCH_POSTS', payload: response.data})
}
```

Comment: `fetchPosts` is a function that *returns* a function (`dispatch`). It's not one function, it's two functions.

Comment: also I'm not sure `dispatch()` will work properly; where did this code come from?

Comment: Thankyou, it does work fetchPosts is being called by another function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How would I re-write the below using 'function' instead and not the '=>'

The code you shared is a function which returns another function. Translated into regular functions it would look like this:

```
function fetchPosts () {
  return async function (dispatch) {
    const response = await jsonPlaceholder.get('/posts')
    dispatch ({type: 'FETCH_POSTS', payload: response.data})
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. It's not working just with arrow function, you're creating a promise too. I believe that it makes more confuse for beginners.

Let unconsidering the promise first, if you have a closure like this.

```
const fetchPosts = () => dispatch => {}
```

It's the same of.

```
// I removed the promise to be easier to understand the composition
function fetchPosts() {
  return function(dispatch) {

  }
}
```

But you have a promise. It could be something like this.

```
function fetchPosts() {
  return function (dispatch) {
    jsonPlaceholder.get('/posts')
      .then(function(response) { 
         dispatch({type: 'FETCH_POSTS', payload: response.data})
      });
  }
}
```

You can use the same syntax `async/await` for promise with functions too.

```
function fetchPosts() { 
  return async function(dispatch) { 
    const response = await jsonPlaceholder.get('/posts') 
    dispatch({type: 'FETCH_POSTS', payload: response.data}) 
  } 
}
```

Comment: `It's the same` No, it's not the same. You removed async/await. `jsonPlaceholder.get()` is asynchronous and isn't awaited, that's a bug.

Comment: You can use the same syntax for promise, using functions too. 
```
function fetchPosts() {
  return async function(dispatch) {
    const response =  await jsonPlaceholder.get('/posts')
    dispatch({type: 'FETCH_POSTS', payload: response.data})
  }
}
```

Comment: @JeremyThille It's the same of my example above, I removed the `async/await` to make simpler the example. Just to he understand the composition of functions without the promise, obvious it's a bug

Comment: @JeremyThille I edited to be more understanble what I'm trying to explain.